# Is there a need to define what kind of 確率 is spoken about?

Tags: grammar, meaning, omission

This sentence is taken from the 5th chapter of the Guilty Gear Web-Comic, which you can find here:

All Chapters: https://www.guiltygear.com/ggst/jp/story/

Chapter 5 (sentence on page 4): https://www.guiltygear.com/ggst/jp/news/post-784/

Context: After Valentine, a being from another world with the wish to erase all humans from earth meets two of the main characters she says the following:

> 「逃げない　**確率**の低い方の人たちだ」

(The space is used to indicate where the text was split within the original speech bubble).

I think that I understand the sentence. Valentine simply says that people like the protagonists who choose not to run away are rare.
I am however a bit unsure about how 「**確率**」  is used here. I rechecked the English definition (https://jisho.org/search/kakuritu%20) and Japanese definition as well (https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%A2%BA%E7%8E%87/). Both articles mention that the word basically means “the chances of something going to happen,” so I kind of have the feeling that some kind of “defining word” of 「**確率**」is omitted here (as we usually need to know what that something is).

For example in a phrase like 「クマに襲われる確率」the kind of probability (確率) is clearly defined. So I thought that the sentence in question in an abbreviated version of something like:

「出会う**確率**の低い方の人たちだ」

This however, might just be me failing to understand the real meaning behind the original sentence or the real meaning of 「**確率**」.

Long story short, I first had difficulties with understanding the sentence mentioned above, because I felt like “a defining phrase” for 「**確率**」was missing. Therefore, my question is whether the sentence has an omitted “defining phrase” or is my understanding of the word 「**確率**」just off?

Comment: Have you checked the English version? https://www.guiltygear.com/ggst/en/news/post-787/ It's translated as: "You haven't fled. Statistically, there are not many people like you." This might be of some help, maybe?

Comment: I checked out the English version as well but still felt like the word 「確率」in the original sentence just doesn’t mean “statistically” as in the translation. I wanted to make sure whether my assumptions of how this sentences works grammatically (and in terms of omission) is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

確率 may not be explicitly modified by a relative clause when a listener can infer what type of 確率 is being talked about. Here, you can think of it as an abbreviated version of 私が出会う確率の低い方の人たちだ. 確率が低い basically just means "rare", so you can read it simply as "rare people", too. (Judging from the entire chapter, she seems to speak somewhat like a robot or a *chunibyo* character, so don't worry if you feel her Japanese is unnatural.)

> 逃げない。確率の低い方の人たちだ。
> You're not running away. You are one of those rare people (who don't run away from me upon seeing me).

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, in GG2, almost every people she met have fled from her sight(Well, since she literally threatened every mankind at very early in the story, so...).

Still, those with courage and/or strength didn't run from her, they fought.

The number of people who actually fought is unknown since it's not stated in the story, but of course it's not many. So, I think that's why she said "出会う確率の低い方の人たちだ" - Basically means "Rare kind of peoples(=people that doesn't flee) that I(Valentine) met".

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about the manga, but the first impression I got from your explanation is that it refers to their chances of survival. She could be casually mentioning the probability of people who don’t run away surviving an encounter with her as she coldly calculates. Then, the “defining word” might be omitted on purpose to make her sound like someone who sees people only as statistics.

Of course, it could simply mean her chances of meeting such people as you and the other answers suggest, though.